# Conditional formatting of a table based on values in a second dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

Assume this example:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10, C = 11:15)
df2 <- data.frame(A = c(1:3,7,5), B = c(11, 7:10), C = 16:20) 

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    df1
  }, digits = 0
  )
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    df2
  }, digits = 0
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(h3("Table Formatting"), align = "center"),
  div(tableOutput("table1"),align = "center"), 
  div(tableOutput("table2"), align = "center")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Is it possible to format the first table based on the data of the second table? Let's say I want that the font of the first table's values becomes green if the value in the second table at the same position is the same. Red if the values are not equal.

For example `df1[1,1] = df2[1,1] = 1`, so this should be green. But `df1[4,1] = 4` is not the same as `df2[4,1] = 7`, so the font in `df1[4,1]` should be red.

I don't care if the formatting is based on data.table, formattable or something completely different, as long as it is usable in shiny.

Thanks in advance!

> You can find the full answer in my own post. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for you:

```
library("shiny")
library("formattable")

df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10, C = 11:15)
df2 <- data.frame(A = c(1:3,7,5), B = c(11, 7:10), C = 16:20) 

ident <- function(...){
  args <- c(...) 
  if( length( args ) > 2L ){
    #  recursively call ident()
    out <- c( identical( args[1] , args[2] ) , ident(args[-1]))
  }else{
    out <- identical( args[1] , args[2] )
  }    
  return( all( out ) )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(h3("Table Formatting"), align = "center"),
  div(formattableOutput("table1"),align = "center"), 
  div(formattableOutput("table2"), align = "center")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table2 <- renderFormattable({formattable(df2, list(A = formatter("span", style = x ~ style(color= ifelse(x == df1$A & x == 1,"green", ifelse(!x == df1$A, "red", NA))))))})

  output$table1 <- renderFormattable({formattable(df1)})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have used for this purpose `formattable` package. I have just used the format for `df2` and the same thing you should use for `df1` in `server`. I hope this will keep you going. It exactly does what you wanted: when `df1$A == df2$A` and `= 1` then green, if `!df1$A == df2$A` then red.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response @Mal_a! This is almost what I wanted. You did it for one column now, but I need it for all columns. I know I can go on in the formattable-list in `output$table2` with `B = formatter(...)`, but a more generic way would be better. I guess you can handle that with `lapply()` and `c("A", "B", "C")` as an argument? If you could add this to your code, it would be the perfect answer! :)

Comment: Found a solution myself. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution of Mal_a I found away to set the format for all columns in a generic way. I used `eval(parse(text = "..."))`. You can create any desired code as a string by a for loop.

```
library("shiny")
library("formattable")

df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10, C = 11:15)
df2 <- data.frame(A = c(1:3,7,5), B = c(11, 7:10), C = 16:20) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(h3("Table Formatting"), align = "center"),
  div(formattableOutput("table1"),align = "center"), 
  div(formattableOutput("table2"), align = "center")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # output$table2 <- renderFormattable({formattable(df2, list(A = formatter("span", style = x ~ style(color= ifelse(x == df1$A,"green", ifelse(!x == df1$A, "red", NA))))))})

      output$table2 <- renderFormattable({
      # the following string argument can be created by a for-loop
        eval(parse(text = "formattable(df2, list(A = formatter('span', style = x ~ style(color= ifelse(x == df1$A,'green', ifelse(!x == df1$A, 'red', NA)))),
                                                 B = formatter('span', style = x ~ style(color= ifelse(x == df1$B,'green', ifelse(!x == df1$B, 'red', NA)))),
                                                 C = formatter('span', style = x ~ style(color= ifelse(x == df1$C,'green', ifelse(!x == df1$C, 'red', NA))))))"))

      })

      output$table1 <- renderFormattable({formattable(df1)})
    }
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result:
[image]